# Internet disable programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, connection, http-proxy

I made a cybercafé application where the internet connectivity is a vital issue. I want to disable the internet connection until any user login in my application.

At first the task is done by disable the Proxy server.  But this is not a perfect solution for me because my users use Mozilla Firefox which facilitates some network settings like *use no proxy*, *use system proxy*, *auto detect proxy* or *manually configure proxy*.  So when a user changes those settings from *system proxy* to *no proxy*, then my application fail to stop them from  browsing.

Please give me some example. I made this application using C#, WPF, SQL server 2008.

Comment: is your app trying to block browsing from browsers on the machine or just from your application?

Comment: This should be done on your router.

Comment: http://www.turnofftheinternet.com/

Comment: No, you can't do this programmatically. There's always a way around it, unless you have the machine locked down using Group Policy. And if you've done that, you can restrict Internet access without having to write an application to do it. Ask more about that on Server Fault. Accomplishing what you want will not entail a programming solution.

Answer (score 1):

To be reasonably certain that there is no access you would have to write an [NDIS filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
This should give you full control over the network, including the ability to block all internet access to anyone except your application (or including).

This is fairly complex and requires learning driver development, and can't be done in c#.